# chrome extension Get the value of generated input

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension taht access the DOM of page and get value of some inputs .
The problem is in the page that i want to access the value of an input text  in my content_script i get :

> Cannot read property 'val' of null

because , the inputs are generated dynamically from a js file that i cann't modify .

i put the :  "run_at" : "document_end" in my manifest file and in the content script i wait the page to be fully loaded

```
 window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed

     // $("input[name$='incident.state']").val();

    var element =$('#incident.state').val();
    alert(element);


},false);
```

Comment: Use [the debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks): set a breakpoint on that line and examine the page source in Elements panel. Also make sure you inject jQuery before your content script.

Comment: i already added the jquery to my content scripts on the begening

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that the inputs are generated dynamically, it may still not exist when `onload` event fires. If you don't want to use something like `setTimeout` to defer retrieving the element, you could use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to react to changes in the DOM, for example, [observing the input being inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277212/mutation-observer-for-creating-new-elements).