# Is there a way to know if a link/script is still pending or has it failed

Tags: javascript, html, dom, promise

I'd like to know from the html below, if `link[rel=import]`, `link[rel=stylesheet]`, `img` and `script` are **pending/loaded/failed/aborted**   without the need to add listeners beforehand and at any point after the event has happened

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="import" href="template-bundle.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header><img src="logo.png" alt="App logo"></header>
    <!-- Boilerplate... -->
    <script src="./app-bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In other words: Is there an interface which provides something similar to a Bluebird's `isPending()`, `isResolved()`, `isRejected()` methods or a regular ES6 Promise?

---

Bonus question: Is this something can be achieved using a Service Worker?

Since SW can intercept requests and know their status, I was wondering if I can implement an API which returns a Promise that

- is pending if request is still pending
- is resolved if `load` event fired
- is rejected if `error` or `aborted` was fired.

Thanks for the help

---

**Update & Solution:**

Thanks to the answers of @pritishvaidya and @guest271314, I was able to come up with a viable solution using [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) that involves watching DOM for additions of resource nodes (link,img,script) and adding a promise to them that will resolve as described above

This works great, with the only caviat that the script tag needs to be inlined in `<head>` before any other resource. [Here's an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mDMGGC75JQFZR6R206qG?p=preview)

```
var resourceNodeSelector = 'link[href],script[src],img[src]';
function watchResource (n) {
    var url = n.href || n.src;

    if (!n.matches || !n.matches(resourceNodeSelector)) {
        return;
    }

    if (n.status) {
        return;
    }

    n.status = resourceObserver.promises[url] = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        n.addEventListener('load', resolve);
        n.addEventListener('error', reject);
        n.addEventListener('abort', reject);
        n.addEventListener('unload', function (l) { delete resourceObserver.promises[url]} );
    });
    n.status.catch(function noop () {}); //catch reject so that it doesn't cause an exception
}

var resourceObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    document.querySelectorAll(resourceNodeSelector).forEach(watchResource);
});
resourceObserver.promises = {};
resourceObserver.observe(window.document, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

Once the observer is in place, any valid resource element, should have a `status` promise property that you can check at any point in time

```
document.querySelector('link').status.then(linkLoaded).catch(linkFailed)
```

A more elegant solution, that does not involve using the expensive `querySelectorAll`, should be possible with ServiceWorker, since it can be programmed to intercept and keep track of all resource requests and their status

Comment: I'm not interested in the styles specifically. Any resource (link,script, img) that fires [UI Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-uievent-types) would benefit from an interface like this. I mention ServiceWorkers, since they can intercept requests, they might be able to handle the status and provide an API similar to what I'm suggesting

Comment: i think i'll remove the stylesheet link, cause it's distracting people

Comment: Instead of removing the stylesheet link from your question, add all different kinds of loaded resources in your example.

Comment: @trincot i restructured the question to hopefully make more sense

Comment: May be you can refer this link, http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/

Comment: @Dogoku _"without the need to add listeners beforehand"_ Not certain what you mean? Is requirement to not utilize `onload` event of `<link>` element?

Comment: @guest271314 Ideally yes, I'd like to avoid having to have an inline script with a load handler that I attach to all static resources (especially since the [UI events do not bubble](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-uievent-types)). Instead I'm asking if there's an API that the browser can provide (or can be implemented with ServiceWorker) that can give me the status of a resource asynchronously

Comment: Dogoku Well, had composed a prospective Answer using `onload`, `onerror` before reading your last comment about `ServiceWorker` being a requirement. If that Answer does not provide expected result will possible attempt to compose a `ServiceWorker` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize `onload`, `onerror` events of `<link>` element; see [Browser CSS/JS loading capabilities](https://pie.gd/test/script-link-events/) at right column.

Create an object to store status of all `<link>` requests and resolved or rejected `Promise` corresponding to the `<link>` element.

Reject `Promise` at `onerror` event; use `.catch()` chained to `Promise.reject()` to handle error so that `Promise.all()` will not stop processing resolved promises within array passed as parameter. You can also `throw` error from `.catch()` at `onerror` handler to `Promise.all()` if any rejected `Promise` should stop processing of resolved promise within array of promises.

At `window.onload` event handler, use `Promise.all()` to process all resolved links, using same function called before `window.onload` event. 
To wait for results of `Promise.all()` to be available, set `src` of last `<script>` element to `bundle.js` at `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>App</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    var handleLinks = {
      links: [],
      isPending: true
    };

    function handleBeforeLoad() {
      if (document.querySelectorAll("link").length === 0) {   
        console.log("links loading state is pending..", handleLinks.isPending);
      } else {
        handleLinks.isPending = false;
        Promise.all(handleLinks.links)
          .then(function(linksContent) {
            console.log("links resolved:", linksContent
                       , "links loading state is pending.."
                       , handleLinks.isPending);
            linksContent.filter(Boolean).forEach(function(link) {
              // `content` property : html `document`,  `CSSStyleSheet` 
              // requested at `<link>` element
              console.log(link); 
            });
            // load `bundle.js`
            document.getElementById("bundle")
            .src = "bundle.js"

          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("link error:", err.message)
          })
      }
    }
    handleBeforeLoad();
    window.onload = handleBeforeLoad;

    function handleLink(el) {
      handleLinks.links.push(Promise.resolve({
        content: el.import || el.sheet,
        type: el.type,
        rel: el.rel,
        href: el.href,
        integrity: el.integrity,
        isResolved: true
      }));

    }

    function handleLinkError(el) {
      handleLinks.links.push(Promise.reject(new Error(JSON.stringify({
        error: "error loading link",
        type: el.type,
        rel: el.rel,
        href: el.href,
        integrity: el.integrity,
        isRejected: true
      }))).catch(function(err) {
        // handle error
        console.log(err);
        // this will return a resolved Promise
        return "error requesting link " + el.href;
        // `throw err` here if any rejected Promise should
        // stop `Promise.all()` from handling resolved Promise
      }));

    }
  </script>
  <link onload="handleLink(this)" 
        onerror="handleLinkError(this)" 
        rel="import" 
        href="template-bundle.html" 
        type="text/html">
  <link onload="handleLink(this)" 
        onerror="handleLinkError(this)" 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        href="bundle.css" 
        type="text/css">
  <!-- this should throw error, file does not exist -->
  <link onload="handleLink(this)" 
        onerror="handleLinkError(this)" 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        href="bundles.css" 
        type="text/css">

  <body>
    <header><img src="" alt="App logo"></header>
    <!-- Boilerplate... -->
    <script id="bundle"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/DQj9yTDcoQJj3h7rGp95?p=preview

Comment: I like your thinking with the exception of the inline handlers (onload/onerror attributes). That gave me an idea of using a MutationObserver to detect link/img/script tag being added to the DOM and attaching the handlers that way. Also the document.querySelectorAll("link") in your beforeLoad function, will never return anything, since that part of the HTML is not yet parsed

Comment: _"Also the document.querySelectorAll("link") in your beforeLoad function, will never return anything, since that part of the HTML is not yet parsed"_ Yes, that is the expectation at that point in `document`; that is, using same function twice for different purposes. Event attributes can be substituted for `.addEventListener()`, where same result should occur. What is purpose of using `ServiceWorker` or `MutationObserver`? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to know if a link failed to load, without me having to explicitly add an onload/onerror attribute to the HTML. I would also like to be able to get this information after this event has happened. You gave me an idea of using MutationObserver to add those handlers on the fly, which should work, but perhaps ServiceWorkers would remove the need of handlers all together, since a SW can intercept all requests and can be programmed to provide a nice Promise-like API

Comment: @Dogoku Not certain how `MutationObserver` could assist in what you are trying to achieve? Though `ServiceWorker` should return expected result, without using event handlers.

Comment: A MutationObserver can inform me when a new link/img/script node has been added to the DOM ([example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13278380/424052)). Then I can add the listeners to the node using `addEventListener` and the rest is similar to what you are doing

Comment: Yes, am familiar with `MutationObserver`. You linked to an Answer which uses jQuery, where instead of `MutationObserver` you can delegate the event to the parent element using `$(parentElement).on("load", "link", function() {// do stuff})`

Comment: The jquery usage is irrelevant, i was just showing an example of MutationObserver. Anyway thanks for your help. I'm working on a POC now. I'll accept your answer once I have something working

Answer (score 0):

yes you can check this in developer tool.Right click on web page and select inspect then window will open seleck network option and there you can check the status.

Comment: I think OP means a way for the website to check this, not the iser.