# how to listen for net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to catch the error when `css` file or `js` file not loaded by the browser

what I'm looking for is something like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="#status">Status : ...</h1>
  </body>

  <script>
    docuement.whenLoadErrorHappen = function () 
    {
        document.findElementById("status").innerHTML = "Error Loading File";
    }
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe try a try-catch block.
Somehow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970475/get-all-javascript-errors-on-page-javascript-error-handling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `error` event attached to `<link>` and, or `<script>` element, see [Is there a way to know if a link/script is still pending or has it failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824927/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-a-link-script-is-still-pending-or-has-it-failed/39908873?s=1|0.1926#39908873)

Answer (score 0):

For checking `css` file exist or not, Just check if a `<link>` element exists with the `href` attribute set to your CSS file's URL:

```
  if (!$("link[href='/path/to.css']").length){
      // css file not exist
  }
```

and for `js`

```
if (!$("script[src='/path/to.js']").length){
     // js file not exist
}
```

Comment: How does the approach at Answer actually check if the request for the file is successful or not?