# How to export an array of objects in a JSON file and then import using es6

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have an array of objects in a json file. I'm trying to import this file into another file so I can reference the data in a simple react project.

I've tried various combinations of export default and named exports but the JSON file is always complaining when I save it. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

(File1.json)

```
    [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
      }
    ]
```

File2.js

```js
import data from '.\file1.json'

console.log(data.id);
```

The issue I'm having is that I see no errors in my JS file but the data.id value isn't being displayed. However in my JSON file, I am having problems exporting it to use.

**Question**: How to import ".json" file (not ".js") with objects  file using es6?

***Update*** I've managed to make it work in the create-react-app environment, I left the json file as an array of objects, then in the js file I used "import xyx from './xyz';"

This worked for me, this answer isn't mentioned in the duplicate marked post so I think it should have it's own answer - hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Complaining about what exactly?

Comment: Export is an ES6 Feature and not a feature of JSON, JSON is a different standard to ES6, [rfc7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Verifiable, Complete example.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated the code to just demonstrate what I am trying to do, basically I'd like to make the data from this file be available to be imported into another file in a variable e.g.   "import sample from 'sample.json'

Comment: @Teemu It complains on the export keyword - saying it expects an array or object literal

Comment: @MartinBarker that's correct, I'm trying to use it as a default export from one file to use as an import in a JS file.

Comment: Apologies, the actual code is on another machine, so I'm not able to paste the exact file in at the moment.

Comment: I have never tried this before, I'm able to make imports and exports work with functions or variables etc in JS files but I've never done it with a JSON file in this way, it's a learning exercise for me as a noob.

Comment: @jobe `Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0` are you getting this error ?

Comment: @Ry to be fair the question title mentions exports and imports with es6 but I'm just looking for an answer now  :)

Comment: @jobe: Right, but the important part is the file extension. (Although I’m still not sure how you could get both a JSON parsing error when using `export default` and no data without it. Are there multiple environments involved? Are you using a transpiler?)

Comment: @Ry- Ok, if you're able to take it off hold and maybe if you can help with the answer that would help me a lot, thanks again.

Comment: @jobe: Or did you determine “no data” from `console.log(data.id)` producing `undefined`? It should be `data[0].id`, since the export is an array.

Comment: @Ry- sorry my bad as I don't have the actual code to hand but I am using a forEach method on the array.

Comment: I'm a noob so not even sure people use JSON files this way or if it's a common thing to do, I couldn't find many examples online.

Comment: Well, I hope these questions give you an idea of why the actual code is important =) Will you be able to edit in the actual code sometime later? In the meantime, knowing the environment would also help, e.g. native modules in browser, native modules in Node.js experimental, ESM bundler, magic ESM shim, …

Comment: @Ry- I'm using create-react-app and in the basic app, I have the app.js file which is importing this JSON file. I'd like to display values from this JSON data.

Comment: @jobe Can I know why you don't want to load your json file dynamically using ajax?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski this is a learning exercise I'm trying to do, I haven't started using ajax or other ways yet.

Comment: @jobe so in my opinion your question is pure abstract/theoretical and probably will be never used in practice because usually we import .js files with code (not .json files with data) - and probably this is bad practice (counter-desing)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I have a practical exercise which requires me to do it, if it's possible to be done, I should be able to do it. I'm sure there are cases when you may have a static file to import data from.

Comment: @jobe yes but if you have static file with data then you just use ".js" file (not ".json" file)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Yes I agree and I know that way will work but I've been asked to do it with a JSON file.

Comment: @jobe don't get me wrong - I don't say that theoretical questions are bad

Comment: @jobe your json file is invalid - `export default sample = `  are not allowed in json file - I edit your question and fix this problem

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Yes I know it's invalid, I was merely trying to show what I'm trying which isn't working.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I have tried the solutions in the duplicate post and none of them worked for me.

Comment: "*I think it should have it's own answer*" - yes, please post a new answer over there!

Comment: @Bergi It already has an accepted answer over there.

Comment: @jobe Doesn't mean that you can't add another one. It might not get accepted by the OP, but will certainly be upvoted by everyone who's working in a create-react-app environment as well.

Comment: @jobe Are there any restrictions on how the URL string is constructed within `<script type="module">`? Can `fetch()` be used within the procedure as long as `import` is used?

Comment: @guest271314 in question title OP says that import must be done using es6 - so `fetch()` as far I know is not allowed because is not part of es6

Comment: @jobe solution in your update is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34946395/860099) but its uses webpack so it cannot apply to your question (es6 only allowed). So update your question

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Technically `import` and `export` is part of the WHATWG HTML Standard https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-module-system some of the same authors of  the Fetch Standard https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/. What exactly do you mean by _"es6"_? What specification are you referring to which defines the mechanism of `import` and `export` that is not the HTML Standard?

Comment: @guest271314 I think es6 is described [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) I cannot find there information about `fetch` but I can find there info about `import`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski That does not negate the fact that `import` and `export` are defined in the HTML Standard and maintained by the WHATWG. The `javascript` tag is at the question, which includes `Fetch`. The text of the question does not explicitly restrict how the URL passed to `import` can be constructed, thus the question to the OP.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're storing as ***`JSON extension`*** you should not use `export const data = ...`

You should directly store the data

*`xyz.json`*

```
[
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
      }
    ]
```

[JSON](https://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json)

[For demo you can see this](https://repl.it/@VivekJain1/ImportantFriendlyWebmaster)

Or you can set extension to `.js`

```
export const data = ...some data
```

at required place

```
import {data} from '../filepath'
```

Comment: How is then imported to be used in another file? I tried this method also but none of the data then appears in the other file?

How would the import statement look if both files are in the same folder?

Comment: @jobe you can see here https://repl.it/@VivekJain1/ImportantFriendlyWebmaster

Comment: Is it possible to do this in es6 using modules and import statements? I thought they can be used instead of require statements. This is the exact problem though.

Comment: @jobe yes it can be all we need is to setup transpiler. i am not familiar with `REPL` but wait let me try to do it

Comment: ok - I am reading some other posts too.

Comment: Any luck Code Maniac?

Answer (score -1):

One workaround for the default HTML standard prohibition of importing files not served as `*/javascript` is to use `fetch()` to get the file, then `export` the result as `default` and `import` a `data URL`

```
<script type="module">
  (async() => {
    let {default:sample} = await import(`data:application/javascript,${encodeURIComponent('export default ')}${JSON.stringify(await(await fetch('file.json')).json())}`);
    console.log(sample);
  })()
</script>
```

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ld8spRk5A6lKGvjRmgum?p=preview)

See also [ES6 modules in local files - The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ/48217124#48217124)

Comment: @guest271314 I will try that but a developer friend of mine mentioned not having to change the file extension to make it work - it does work the way you're suggesting but I'm trying to see if the JSON extension method will work.

Comment: @jobe `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` Did your "developer friend" share working code with you to prove their claim?

Comment: @guest271314 No he didn't it was meant to be my learning exercise to make it work. He did show me a working version with a JSON file but not in detail.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski How do you propose to include `export` in a valid `JSON` file?

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to find a way to do it with a JSON file extension.

Comment: @jobe Why does the extension need to be `.json`? As pointed out above, you can use `<link rel="import">` or `fetch()`. Or use non-standard third-party code (as suggested in the linked question). Valid `JSON` cannot contain an `export` statement preceding valid `JSON`, which would result in invalid `JSON`.  Refer to the HTML Standard https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-module-system

Comment: @jobe See also [Is there a way to know if a link/script is still pending or has it failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39824927/)

Comment: @jobe The requirement is currently not possible using JavaScript shipped with the browser for the reasons stated above. First there is the issue of an `export` statement in valid `JSON` which would render the `JSON` invalid. Have you read the linked specification?

Comment: It might have got missed but I mentioned in another comment I am doing this in create-react-app which has webpack etc all bundled up. Some posts I have read suggest this is possible.

Comment: @jobe According to answers at the linked question the requirement apparently is possible using non-standard, third-party code which transforms or modifies the request/response - not standard, non-third-party default methods shipped with the browser. Have not tried webpack or react. The answer is based on standard HTML and JavaScript shipped with the browser - without using any third-party, non-standard code or libraries.

Comment: @jobe Note HTML Imports are deprecated for Chromium/Chrome 73 https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376