# Is there a way to apply jQuery to dynamically created elements? (not event listeners)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, element

I have dynamically created an element with the following class:

```
<span class="text">Hello</span>
```

and jQuery:

```
function changeText() {
   var oldText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(oldText + " There");
}

$(function() {
    $(".text").each(function(){
        changeText.apply(this);
    })
})
```

Obviously, this is a simplified version of what is actually happening but the basics are there. Is it possible to apply this rule to dynamically created elements even though we are not using event listeners?

The problem here is that there is no specific location for these ".text" elements. The only place we know these will show up is in the body. I we use a mutationObserver on the body... wouldn't that be taxing performance?

Comment: The best way is to alter the function responsible for the creation of those dynamic elements.

Comment: Can you change the code responsible for the creation of the dynamic elements?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is using an antiquated framework to do this.

Comment: Are the dynamic elements only appended to one parent elements? Or there is more of those parent elements?

Comment: I figured if it was possible to persist event binding to dynamically created elements, then it _should_ be possible to apply jQuery to these as well.

Comment: It varies, the only for sure thing is that it will have the class.

Comment: Look at MutationObserver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mutation Observer for creating new elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277212/mutation-observer-for-creating-new-elements)

Comment: well if that's the only way to do it... then I suppose its what I will have to use.

Comment: I will try this and report back. thanks fellas.

Comment: If you need to support IE, MutationObsever is a non-starter. You could probably hack something with `window.setInterval` and `document.querySelectorAll('.text')` as an alternative.

Comment: Yikes yeah I need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
function changeText() {
  var oldText = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(oldText + ' There');
}
$(function(){
$('.text').each(function(i, e){
  changeText.call(e);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$dynamicElement.find(".text").each(function(){
    changeText.apply(this);
})
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP needs.

Comment: the `find` method keeps looking for those elements even after the page is loaded?

Comment: Looks like, no. Sorry this isn't what I'm looking for. Any tips to make my question more clear?

Comment: no the find method looks on the dynamic element. for example if you create a div after page load the div would be the dynamic element and find searches the div only