# How to put a EventListener for all divs generated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a complex project: a Youtube UI clone, and I had a problem with JS

### the idea

the idea is: on scroll more divs should be created automatically, similar to the first one (and that's working fine)

#### the problem

but when I want to put an event listener for `click`, JavaScript does not handle the events on subsequent divs,
but in reality, there are automatically generated 50 ~ 100 other divs (with the same class)
so I think there is something wrong with `.length`

### here the website for giving you a idea of the problem:

https://laaouatni.github.io/yt-clone/

### here where I think the problem is:

```js
function createVideo() {
    let videoComponent = videoContainer.cloneNode(true);
    mainContainer.appendChild(videoComponent);
}
```

```html
...

    <main>
        <div class="video-container">

           ...

        </div>
        <!-- here javascript will put other divs on scroll -->
    </main>

...
```

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
   let scrollPercentage = (window.scrollY / (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight)) * 100;

    if (scrollPercentage > 70) {
        createVideo();
    }
}
```

```js
let videoContainer = document.querySelector(".video-container");
let allVideoContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".video-container");

for (let index = 0; index < allVideoContainer.length; index++) {
    allVideoContainer[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("clicked video N " + index);
    })
}
```

if I click the `div` that was written manually, it executes the `click` function, but with the generated divs the `click` does not work. I don't know if the DOM doesn't update or should I write something more? on the internet there is no result for solving the problem (I hope to find someone with experience, who can help me here)

### if you need, for all code github repo (to help us)

https://github.com/Laaouatni/yt-clone

Comment: "a youtube UI clone" - _why_?

Comment: Your `scroll` event-listener needs to be `passive`.

Comment: @Dai what is mean `passive` ? (i am a begginer)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721782/what-are-passive-event-listeners

Comment: event delegation can also solve the problem where your dynamically created divs don't have an event listener attached to them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

When you call `addEventListener`, only the tags that exist receive the event. Future tags that do not exist yet will not have that event. You need to somehow guarantee that future elements also have the event. There are multiple ways that you can use to achieve this.

## onclick

One very simple way to guarantee that your `click` event will be handled is to specify an `onclick` attribute to the tag, like

`onclick="yourfunction`

Example:

```js
function foo(element) {
    alert([...element.parentNode.children].indexOf(element));
}

function addDiv() {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML += `
        <p onclick="foo(this);">${container.children.length}</p>
    `;
};
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addDiv()" value="Click Here!">
<div id="container">
</div>
```

## Adding event listeners on the fly

It is also possible to somehow mark the items that already have been initialized and subsequently add the event only to items that are not yet initialized and subsequently initialize them.

Example:

```js
function foo(element) {
    alert([...element.parentNode.children].indexOf(element));
}

function addDiv() {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML += `
        <p onclick="foo(this);">${container.children.length}</p>
    `;
    
    for (let item of document.querySelectorAll(".container > div:not(.initialized)")) {
        item.addEventListener("click", () => {
            foo(this);
            this.classList.add("initialized");
        });
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addDiv()" value="Click Here!">
<div id="container">
</div>
```

## Adding an event listener to an HTML node

You can simply call `videoComponent.addEventListener`.

Example:

```js
function foo(element) {
    alert([...element.parentNode.children].indexOf(element));
}

function addDiv() {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    let newNode = container.children[0].cloneNode(true);
    newNode.innerText = container.children.length;
    container.appendChild(newNode);
    newNode.addEventListener("click", function() {
        foo(this);
    });
};

document.getElementById("container").children[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    foo(this);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addDiv()" value="Click Here!">
<div id="container">
    <p>0</p>
</div>
```

## Mutation Observer

Courtesy to [Mutation Observer for creating new elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277212/mutation-observer-for-creating-new-elements)

You can use Mutation Observer to detect tag creation and attach events to it. It should be avoided if possible, more often than not you have a simpler solution, but, for the sake of completeness, here's an example taken from the link shared above:

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

$("#foo").live("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).append($("<div />").html("new div").attr("id","bar"));
});

// define a new observer
var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    // look through all mutations that just occured
    for(var i=0; i<mutations.length; ++i) {
        // look through all added nodes of this mutation
        for(var j=0; j<mutations[i].addedNodes.length; ++j) {
            // was a child added with ID of 'bar'?
            if(mutations[i].addedNodes[j].id == "bar") {
                console.log("bar was added!");
            }
        }
    }
});

// have the observer observe foo for changes in children
obs.observe($("#foo").get(0), {
  childList: true
});
```

## Event delegation

Last, but not least, as others already mentioned, you can delegate your event to the parent node, but in that case you will need to find out what the originator of the event was, which is the event object's `target` field.

Example:

```js
function foo(element) {
    alert([...element.parentNode.children].indexOf(element));
}

function addDiv() {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML += `
        <p>${container.children.length}</p>
    `;
};

document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    foo(event.target);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addDiv()" value="Click Here!">
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you're adding your event listeners initially when the page loads. This means that your `for` loop that adds your event listeners will only loop over the `video-container` elements that are present on the initial load of your page. Any `video-container` elements created after you've added your event listeners won't have an event listener attached to them. Even if you are using  [`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) on an element that has an event listener attached with `addEventListener()`, the event listener won't be copied across to the new element as `addEventListener()` event handlers are not copied.

One idea is to add a new event listener to `videoComponent` every time `createVideo()` is called. The problem with this is that this can lead to you adding *many* event listeners to your page, which can slow down the performance of your webpage.

A better idea is to use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). The idea of event delegation is that you can add your event listener to one parent element (in your case the `<main>` element). When one of your `video-container` elements nested under the parent `<main>` element is clicked, the click event will ["bubble" up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#setting_a_listener_on_a_parent_element) to the `<main>` element, triggering the click event listener on the parent `<main>` element. Within the event listener attached to the parent `<main>` element, you can obtain a reference to the originally clicked `video-container` element using `e.target`, where `e` is the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object provided in the event listeners callback function. As the click event listener is on the parent `main` container, the click event listener for any newly created children elements will work, as the event from the child element will bubble up to the parent main container's event handler.

To achieve event delegation in your code, you can remove your `for` loop that adds the individual event listenerrs and instead add your click event listener to your `mainContainer` element. This will capture click events that bubble up to it when its children are clicked:

```js
mainContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e) { // e = event object
  if (e.target && e.target.matches(".video-container")) {
    const clickedVideoContainer = e.target;
    // do stuff with `clickedVideoContainer`
  }
});
```

Here we're also checking that the clicked element (`e.target`) is in fact a video-container element by seeing if it [`matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) the selector `.video-container`. This is needed as our `mainContainer` event listener can trigger for any click events that bubble up to it from any of its children, grandchildren, etc.

As also noted in the comments by @Dai, you might also want to consider using the [`passive` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners) when adding your scroll event listener to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Nick's answer, yes it is possible to do it with vanilla JS but if JQuery is available it makes it super simple and far more readable.

```js
$(document).on('click','.video-container',function(e){
   //your desired actions
})
```

The first parameter is event type (click, hover etc.). You may use any conventional selector for the second parameter.

Comment: ok, thanks. I upvoted you, but I want to give the bounty to the @Nick because he really helps a lot and writes a super detailed answer, and I think he deserves that point. :) good job!

Comment: But of course, he was the first to answer after all. And i just did a small enhancement to his original answer. Happy to help, cheers !