# Decimal function validation on multiple listener

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.

```
<table class="display table table-striped responsive nowrap ">
  <tbody id="dataTable" class="table" >
    <tr >
      <td>
      <div class="form-row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;" >
          <div><label>kg</label><input class="form-control pesoformat" type="number" name="kg[]" value="0.00" min="0.00" max="1.00" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00" required ></div>
          <div><label>qty</label><input type="number" name="qta[]" class="form-control" required ></div>                                        
          <div><button type="button" class="btn add" id="btnAdd" >ADD NEW ROW</button></div>
     </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>

const table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
const row = table.querySelector('tr');
const renum = () => { 
  let cnt = 0;
  table.querySelectorAll('td:first-child .tst').forEach(input => input.value = ++cnt);
};


table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('[type=button]');
  if (!tgt) return
  if (tgt.matches('.add')) {
    const newRow = row.cloneNode(true);
    newRow.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach(input => input.value = ""); // reset the values
    newRow.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]').forEach(input => input.value = ""); // reset the values
    table.appendChild(newRow);
    renum();
  }
})

var numberElement = document.querySelector(".pesoformat")   
numberElement.addEventListener('change',alterNumber);
function alterNumber(event){
var el = event.target;
var elValue = el.value;
el.value = parseFloat(elValue).toFixed(6);
}

</script>
```

The problem is that the function that formats the decimal value works only on the first row (under kg input field). When I try to add more rows it doesn't work anymore.

I also tried to place the function alterNumber into the  and change

```
numberElement.addEventListener('change',alterNumber);
```

into

```
this.addEventListener('change',alterNumber);
```

A complete example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/9sn3dj4f/

but in this case the function worked also on the new row but also on all input fields... and this is not what i want. I only want that function on the kg input field...

any help?

https://jsfiddle.net/9sn3dj4f/

Comment: Well, what is `this` in your situation?

Comment: you can see in the jsfiddle, when you click on the first qty input, the function to format the value works. Then if you click to add row, the function doesn't work anymore (on the new row I mean)

Comment: @derpirscher  with "this" it seems to work also on the second row, but the problem is that it works on all input fields, and not only on the qty one...

Comment: You are not adding any eventlistener on the newly created inputs.

Comment: Related: [How to put a EventListener for all divs generated by JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70454829)